# Connecting to a smartphone advertised as a beacon

Tags: android, beacon

I'm developing an application using react-native and i'm implementing the react-native-ble-plx library, in fact i'm  advertising a smartphone as beacon using quickbeacon app that i've downloaded it from play store, i detect the advertised smartphone but the problem is that i can't connect to it since it is generating the mac id every time,
is there any way to connect to an advertised smartphone from another smartphone, at least to get sure if it can happen using react-native,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 6+ will spoof it's advertised mac address, so you cannot rely on that to establish a connection.   With native Android APIs, you get a Device object as a result of each scan, and you can use this, rather than the MAC to establish a connection successfully in this case.

I do not know if the react-native-ble-plx library you are usong has bindings for these Native APIs.  If you have a link to the APIs you are using I may be able to augment this answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx that's the link of the library, I don't know if I can get a device object as in android ... but I hope I find a something to test connection

Comment: This doc https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/ says that scanning will return a Decide instance, then you can call device.connect().  Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what i'm doing, and i'm detecting the generated mac id with the scan but device.connect is not working, i think it's because the mac id is generated ??